# Equivalent circuit to power an older device

Tags: electricity

I have an old wartime device that requires a 2.5V 0.1A MES bulb ( the old flashlight kind). However they are now unobtainable in this rating.

As the output of the Bulb would be 0.25W, can an alternative that comes very close to this Wattage in a different combination of Volts and Amps which is available be substituted, eg the closest available is 1.25V and 0.2A which would be 0.25W.

I look forward to your advice

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate the circuit of your old equipment.  How is the lamp powered ? Many older circuits used thermionic valves (aka tubes) and lamps were used in a series chain of the valve heaters. For example a set of 6 valves, all with 100mA heaters could be series connected with the 100mA 2.5V lamp. Until you have investigated the circuit and come back to us we would be speculating about the many possibilities of how your lamp is powered.